# Pandas: expand group variable to encompass the first n obervations of the next group in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Here is my `df` with an example of the two columns that I have to work (`group`and `value`) with and an example of the output that I am trying to achieve(`output_wanted`):

```
egdf = pd.DataFrame({'group': ['A']*6+['B']*6+['C']*5+['D']*6,
                      'value': list(range(1, 7))*2+list(range(1, 6))+list(range(1, 7)),
                      'output_wanted': ['A']*8+['B']*6+['C']*5+['D']*4)
```

The idea is that I would like to expand each group to then encompass the first n (in this example two) entries of the next group in the dataframe. I'm lost for ideas on where to begin here. Has anyone got any idea how one might do this? Note that as in the example, the groups are of unequal sizes... Thanks!

Comment: What is the rationale for output_wanted to be like that for e.g. why 'A' has to be repeated 8 times, B 6 ,C 5 and D 4?

Comment: The idea each group has be expanded to take in the first two rows of the next group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and backfill the first two (n) rows?

```
egdf['output_wanted'] = egdf.group.shift(2).fillna(method='bfill')
```

Where `2` can be replaced by `n` of course. If needed DataFrame could be sorted by `group` first.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how one would do this so it is contained within another grouping level? My problem is that within the dataframe there are points where it shouldn't fill forward any more.

Comment: already got it!: `df['output_wanted'] = df.groupby('second_grouping')['group'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(90).fillna(method='bfill'))`